# My hip goes out of place within a matter of days after the Chiroproactor pops it back into place, is there any way I can pop it back myself?

Tags: back-pain

It is causing a lot of pain on my SI joint when the hip is out of place, Saturday I went to the Chrio and he popped it back in place, Sunday I noticed a huge improvement in my movement. By the end of the day Sunday, it was back out again. Now it's Monday and the pain is back, I'm sick of going into the office to get fixed and it only lasts a few days. Is there any technique for a self re-adjustment of the hip?

Comment: Is there a way you "can"? Sure. Should you go to the doctor instead? Absolutely. Talk to your doctor or chiropractor about why it keeps coming out of place and see what they suggest. If your chiropractor doesn't give you anything, talk to an actual medical doctor (M.D.) about it and see if they can find a better solution for you.

Comment: @md5sum 'Sure.' do you know how?

Comment: Ask your chiropractor about exercises to strengthen the appropriate muscles to address this issue.

Comment: This seems to be a medical question - treating an injury, rather than preventing a new one during an exercise.

Comment: For what it's worth, off-topic as it is, I have the same issues with my SI joints due to an old injury. I know the maneuver that the chiro is doing to you, which helps a lot. Look into something called a 'Trochanter Belt', which is a brace you wear low around your helps. At least in my case, when it gets bad, the belt helps keep everything in place while the swelling goes down in the joint, so everything stays 'in place' and doesn't wander. The joint isn't "out of place" in so much as swelling in the joint is hindering movement.

Comment: @StyxRiver thanks, I have a similar situation, I have a degenerative disc which causes the muscles to try and compensate and subsequently screwing up my SI joints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I'm not a doctor, and you seriously should talk to yours to see if they can come up with a more permanent solution for you. However, depending on how badly out of place it is, you can sometimes put it back by sitting on the floor on your butt with your feet out, legs straight, then spread your legs apart. If it's badly out, this could fail and you could seriously injure yourself. If it's bad enough that this doesn't help, you could also have a friend help you do the Allis Maneuver.

In the Allis Maneuver, lay on your back, legs straight, and your friend should pull against your hip while pressing your pelvis down, rotating your leg up to a 90 degree angle with your back, knee bent at a 90 degree angle, then with a great deal of force pulling your leg up and pressing your pelvis down. This requires a great deal of force, and hurts really bad from what I understand. It is also very dangerous and you could end up (once again) seriously injuring yourself.

There is also the Stimson Maneuver, which would likely require 2 friends' assistance. I would advise very strongly against using any of the methods I've listed, and would urge you to go talk to your doctor. These maneuvers listed here could cause serious, permanent damage to your body.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, thanks. My chiropractor does a really simple move where I lay on my side and put my top arm over my head, and bend my top knee, then he just kind of crunches me. If I had a second person I could just have them learn that, but I want to do it by myself. I mean I can still walk around find, it's not like it's out of socket, it's just slightly misaligned or something. I asked the chiro if there was a way to do it myself and he just kind of brushed it off and said 'if there was I wouldn't have to have someone else adjust me' but I think it might be a marketing ploy.

Comment: If you can still walk, it likely isn't out of place. Talk to a real doctor (M.D.) and find out what's really going on.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem that was waking me up from sleep because of thepain, yet I could walk reasonably ok.  The Chiro popped it in place which brought some relief, but it lasted less than two days.

Doing a bit of research, I found that the best way for me to pop the hip back is actuall very simple.

1. Lie flat on your back with arms spread wide.  Legs stretched out straight.
2. Raise the leg with the popped/misaligned hip joint so that it is 90 deg to the floor.  (you can bend your leg at the knee if you desire)
3. Let the leg down slowly to the side until you hear/feel the joint pop back into place.
   Initially I had to do this twice a day, now as the muscles have got stronger again, I need to do it only once or twice a week.

Simple and effective

Answer (score 1):

If you will do some research, you will find that a Doctor of Chiropractic [DC] is highly trained in spinal manipulation - far more than a MD.  Self spinal manipulation can be very dangerous and cause serious injuries.  If you want to help your spinal condition, learn proper rehab exercises designed specifically for your condition by a DC or PT.  Counsult a DC who utilizes spinal imaging and works with other health care specialists to achieve the best correction for your problem.

God Bless, Sam

Answer (score 1):

I've done a variety of sports and dancing over the years, and due to all this, my hips get misaligned and pop in and out very often. Although I can walk, it's often very painful to do so. This is what's going on with you, right?

There's a stretch my soccer team used which we call "opening and closing the gate." While standing, take the leg with the misaligned hip and raise the knee high, pushing out to the side as far as it will go (this is opening the gate). It should make a circular motion. Repeat a couple a times, then reverse the motion, going from outside-in (closing the gate).

As a martial artist, I use high kicks which follow the above mentioned circular path to do the same thing. I find that sticking my misaligned leg directly out to the side and stretching over it helps pop it back with the opening and closing the gate thing faster. Also, with opening the gate, you can leg your leg go down at the end of opening it, so your foot goes behind you. It tests pretty much all the movement of your hip, hopefully letting something move back in place.

You can also lay on a table (or bed, or whatever else that is sufficiently high off the ground) with your butt and lower back on the edge, your legs hanging off. Keeping your legs straight, let the injured one drop a little bit at a time until it clicks back into place. This option doesn't always work, and I admit that I found it by accident. This works really well if your hip was misaligned due to a split or similar movement.

Have you ever seen ballerinas grab their foot behind them and lift it above their head? You can try that too, which pulls the leg backward, stretching the hip and sometimes popping it back in. I suggest having a wall or sofa in front of you to lean on though, because with both hands on your leg you have to have amazing balance not to fall over.

You can also get on one knee, with the injured leg down, and rotate side to side. The farther back the downed knee is, the better the stretch -- but also the harder it is to rotate. Do this slow; quick movements can cause further injury.

I'm really sorry your hips are bothering you (and that I'm 2 years after this thread), but I hope all this helps you. 
Note: I'm not claiming to give valid medical advice -- I'm just stating what has worked for me to realign my hips.

Answer (score 0):

A chiropractor can do nothing for you other than pop it back in. I have this problem. You need to go to physical therapy and they can do different exercises for you which will help in time. My hip causes my lower back to hurt really bad and my leg on the side of my affected hip to have a throbbing pain. It hurts all the time and hurts more when I run or do any physical activity.

You also may have snapping hip syndrome which I was told I had. It causes you a lot of pain too and has similar pains but its where your tendons and muscles are too tight or too loose and your hip clicks over the group of muscles that run across your hip. I have been told that my hip pops in and out and wont stay in by physical therapists, but the DOC doctor said it was snapping hip syndrome.

So therefore, I do not know. I'm still getting physical therapy to find out what exactly is wrong and how to fix it. Either way it is hard to sleep and move and have a lot of back pain that comes with it. Check out snapping hip syndrome.

Answer (score 0):

I have Sciatica and now my hip has popped out of place (been out about 4 months now since falling). I had a car wreck in 2008 and my hip was out of place then but I was able to work it back into place through working out and getting adjustments. However since I have fallen and popped it back out, I've been struggling to get it back into place so I can work out.

I have found that sleeping with a pillow helps and have looked up some physical therapy exercises on YouTube but just started using the techniques today. I have been told that stretching helps but honestly I can't afford to keep going to the chiropractor as after going to him for two months 3 times a week I'm still out of place.

I have stumbled across an exercise that pops my hip back in at least momentarily. Put a pillow in between your legs and bend down in the squat position keeping your legs together and pushing in with your legs slightly squeezing the pillow as your bending.

Comment: Note that this is a Q&A site and not a forum, check the [about] page to get an understanding how the site works. Currently I am not really sure if your answers really answers the question or is a question on its own.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to mention all the exercise suggested to you and explain them to make it clear for everyone.